# Correct density

Tags: geometry

I sampled organisms using a circular quadrat with a radius of $0.5m$. I need to calculate the density of organisms within that area but since $0.79m$ is an odd way to report that, I need to scale it up as if I had sampled within a $1m^2$ plot. I want to ensure I've done the calculations correctly before reporting my results. Here's how I have solved this so far:

Density = # of individuals/area sampled

Area of a circle: $\pi\times r^2 = 3.14\times0.5^2 = 0.79$

Area of a square: $a^2 = 1m^2$

Can I just subtract the area of a circle from the square $1-0.79 = 0.21$ and use that in my density equation? So for example, if I had $13$ organisms in $1$ quadrat, I would just do: $13/(0.79\times0.21)$ or $13/0.1659$?

Thanks for your insight!

Comment: You correctly stated the definition of density: for 13 organisms in your quadrat density is $13/0.7854=16.55$ organisms$/$m$^2$.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to assume how many organisms were outside the circle, therefore the density you receive will be only dependent on the area inside the circle. Density in this case is in the unit $nm^2$ were $n$ is the number of organisms and therefore your density already gives the number of organisms per meter squared of ground without up scaling it.

Density = # of individuals/area sampled

By dividing by area sampled you go from a number of organisms to a number of organisms per meter squared, and therefore your answer is already correct.